# C# Panel from outside Program.cs using VSCode

Tags: c#

So I have this GUI program that I have been working on and have my Program holding most of the items in it. But as the program gets larger , the Program.cs file gets longer and harder to find where things are within it. So I want to start pulling any Panel I create out of the main Program file into there own class.

But not able to figure out how to use the Panel in the main C# file.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Drawing.Text;

//Most of the following code works and does produce the window
//Having to work on converting from the Java coud that works to C#
//This is now working and continueing to build it up.

namespace unchained{
    public static class Program{
        public static void Main(String [] args){
            Form window = new();
            Panel main = new();
            Panel select = new();
            Panel saved = new();
            Label text = new();
            Label text2 = new();
            Button selectNew = new();
            Button selectExit = new();
            Button savedStart = new();
            Button savedExit = new();

            selectNew.Text = "New Game";
            selectNew.Location = new Point(395, 150);
            selectNew.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            selectNew.Click += newGame;
            
            selectExit.Text = "Exit Select";
            selectExit.Location = new Point(350, 525);
            selectExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            selectExit.Click += backToMain;

            Button startGame = new();
            startGame.Text = "Start Game";
            startGame.Location = new Point(450, 525);
            startGame.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            startGame.Click += startNewGame;

            //Char Building components
            Panel charChoices = new();
            charChoices.Location = new Point(0,0);
            charChoices.Width = 400;
            charChoices.Height = 500;
            charChoices.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            Panel charStats = new();
            charStats.Location = new Point(400,0);
            charStats.Width = 400;
            charStats.Height = 500;
            charStats.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            //Style handling section
            Label styleHeader = new();
            styleHeader.Text = "Select your Style";
            styleHeader.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            styleHeader.Location = new Point(25,25);
            Panel spacer1 = new();
            spacer1.Width = 350;
            spacer1.Height = 3;
            spacer1.Location = new Point(25, 55);
            spacer1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button holy = new();
            holy.Text = "Holy";
            holy.Location = new Point(25, 80);
            holy.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button wise = new();
            wise.Text = "Wise";
            wise.Location = new Point(25, 110);
            wise.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button psychtic = new();
            psychtic.Text = "Psychtic";
            psychtic.Location = new Point(25, 140);
            psychtic.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button stout = new();
            stout.Text = "Stout";
            stout.Location = new Point(125, 80);
            stout.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button veteran = new();
            veteran.Text = "Veteran";
            veteran.Location = new Point(125, 110);
            veteran.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button brutal = new();
            brutal.Text = "Brutal";
            brutal.Location = new Point(125, 140);
            brutal.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button nimble = new();
            nimble.Text = "Nimble";
            nimble.Location = new Point(225, 80);
            nimble.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button balanced = new();
            balanced.Text = "Balanced";
            balanced.Location = new Point(225, 110);
            balanced.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button speedy = new();
            speedy.Text = "Speedy";
            speedy.Location = new Point(225, 140);
            speedy.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            //Race handling section
            Label raceHeader = new();
            raceHeader.Text = "Select your Race";
            raceHeader.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            raceHeader.Location = new Point(25,190);
            Panel spacer2 = new();
            spacer2.Width = 350;
            spacer2.Height = 3;
            spacer2.Location = new Point(25, 220);
            spacer2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button human = new();
            human.Text = "Human";
            human.Location = new Point(25, 245);
            human.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button elven = new();
            elven.Text = "Elven";
            elven.Location = new Point(25, 275);
            elven.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button kobold = new();
            kobold.Text = "Kobold";
            kobold.Location = new Point(25, 305);
            kobold.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button dwarf = new();
            dwarf.Text = "Dwarven";
            dwarf.Location = new Point(125, 245);
            dwarf.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button orc = new();
            orc.Text = "Orc";
            orc.Location = new Point(125, 275);
            orc.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button draco = new();
            draco.Text = "Draco";
            draco.Location = new Point(125, 305);
            draco.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255); 
            Button atlantean = new();
            atlantean.Text = "Atlantean";
            atlantean.Location = new Point(225, 245);
            atlantean.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button undead = new();
            undead.Text = "Undead";
            undead.Location = new Point(225, 275);
            undead.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button grim = new();
            grim.Text = "Grim";
            grim.Location = new Point(225, 305);
            grim.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);            
            //Role handling section
            Label roleHeader = new();
            roleHeader.Text = "Select your Role";
            roleHeader.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            roleHeader.Location = new Point(25,350);
            Panel spacer3 = new();
            spacer3.Width = 350;
            spacer3.Height = 3;
            spacer3.Location = new Point(25, 380);
            spacer3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button paladin = new();
            paladin.Text = "Paladin";
            paladin.Location = new Point(25, 400);
            paladin.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button warrior = new();
            warrior.Text = "Warrior";
            warrior.Location = new Point(25, 430);
            warrior.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button ravager = new();
            ravager.Text = "Ravager";
            ravager.Location = new Point(25, 460);
            ravager.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button magi = new();
            magi.Text = "Magi";
            magi.Location = new Point(125, 400);
            magi.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button cleric = new();
            cleric.Text = "Cleric";
            cleric.Location = new Point(125, 430);
            cleric.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button seer = new();
            seer.Text = "Seer";
            seer.Location = new Point(125, 460);
            seer.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button justicar = new();
            justicar.Text = "Justicar";
            justicar.Location = new Point(225, 400);
            justicar.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button ranger = new();
            ranger.Text = "Ranger";
            ranger.Location = new Point(225, 430);
            ranger.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Button shadow = new();
            shadow.Text = "Shadow";
            shadow.Location = new Point(225, 460);
            shadow.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            //Results section
            Label nameString = new();
            nameString.Text = charSheet.charname;
            nameString.Location = new Point( 25, 25);
            nameString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label selectStyle = new();
            selectStyle.Text = charSheet.style;
            selectStyle.Location = new Point( 25, 55 );
            selectStyle.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label selectRace = new();
            selectRace.Text = charSheet.race;
            selectRace.Location = new Point( 125, 55);
            selectRace.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label selectRole = new();
            selectRole.Text = charSheet.role;
            selectRole.Location = new Point( 225, 55);
            selectRole.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label lvlString = new();
            lvlString.Text = "lvl: "+charSheet.level;
            lvlString.Location = new Point( 25, 85);
            lvlString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label strString = new();
            strString.Text = "Str: "+charSheet.str;
            strString.Location = new Point( 25, 115);
            strString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label conString = new();
            conString.Text = "Con: "+charSheet.con;
            conString.Location = new Point( 25, 145);
            conString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label dexString = new();
            dexString.Text = "Dex: "+charSheet.str;
            dexString.Location = new Point( 25, 175);
            dexString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            Label quiString = new();
            quiString.Text = "Qui: "+charSheet.str;
            quiString.Location = new Point( 25, 205);
            quiString.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            //Event handling section
            holy.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            wise.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            psychtic.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            stout.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            veteran.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            brutal.Click += (sender, e) => styleSelect(sender, e);
            nimble.Click += (Sender, e) => styleSelect(Sender,e);
            balanced.Click += (Sender, e) => styleSelect(Sender,e);
            speedy.Click += (Sender, e) => styleSelect(Sender,e);
            balanced.Click += (Sender, e) => styleSelect(Sender,e);
            speedy.Click += (Sender, e) => styleSelect(Sender,e);
            human.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            elven.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            kobold.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            dwarf.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            orc.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            draco.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            dwarf.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            atlantean.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            undead.Click += (Sender, e) => raceSelect(Sender,e);
            grim.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            paladin.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            warrior.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            ravager.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            magi.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            seer.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            cleric.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            justicar.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            ranger.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            shadow.Click += (Sender, e) => roleSelect(Sender,e);
            //UI section
            select.Width = 800;
            select.Height = 600;
            select.Visible = false;
            select.Controls.Add(charChoices);
            select.Controls.Add(charStats);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(styleHeader);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(spacer1);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(holy);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(wise);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(psychtic);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(stout);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(veteran);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(brutal);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(nimble);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(balanced);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(speedy);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(raceHeader);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(spacer2);            
            charChoices.Controls.Add(human);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(elven);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(kobold);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(dwarf);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(orc);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(draco);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(undead);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(atlantean);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(grim);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(roleHeader);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(spacer3); 
            charChoices.Controls.Add(paladin);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(warrior);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(ravager);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(magi);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(seer);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(cleric);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(justicar);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(ranger);
            charChoices.Controls.Add(shadow);
            select.Controls.Add(selectExit);
            select.Controls.Add(startGame);
            charStats.Controls.Add(nameString);            
            charStats.Controls.Add(lvlString);            
            charStats.Controls.Add(selectStyle);
            charStats.Controls.Add(selectRace);
            charStats.Controls.Add(selectRole);
            charStats.Controls.Add(strString);
            select.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);

            savedStart.Text = "Saved Game";
            savedStart.Location = new Point(395, 250);
            savedStart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            savedStart.Click += savedGame;

            savedExit.Text = "Exit Saved";
            savedExit.Location = new Point(395, 150);
            savedExit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            savedExit.Click += backToMain;

            saved.Width = 800;
            saved.Height = 600;
            saved.Visible = false;
            saved.Controls.Add(savedExit);
            saved.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);

            text.Text = "Unchained";
            //The location is (Width,hieght)
            text.Location = new Point(400,100);
            text.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

            main.Width = 800;
            main.Height = 600;
            main.Visible = true;
            main.Controls.Add(text);
            main.Controls.Add(selectNew);
            main.Controls.Add(savedStart);
            main.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            
            window.Width = 800;
            window.Height = 600;
            window.Text = "Unchained v0.2.12";
            //window.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
            //window.Controls.Add(button);
            window.Controls.Add(main);
            window.Controls.Add(select);
            window.Controls.Add(saved);
            //Dungeon newDungeon = new Dungeon();
            //window.Controls.Add(newDungeon.gamePanel);
            Application.Run(window);

            void styleSelect(object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                Button btn = sender as Button;
                string s = btn.Text;
                charSheet.style = s;
                selectStyle.Text = charSheet.style;
            }

            void raceSelect(object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                Button btn2 = sender as Button;
                string r = btn2.Text;
                charSheet.race = r;
                selectRace.Text = charSheet.race;
            }
            
            void roleSelect(object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                Button btn3 = sender as Button;
                string r2 = btn3.Text;
                charSheet.role = r2;
                selectRole.Text = charSheet.role;
            }

            void newGame(Object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                main.Visible = false;
                select.Visible = true;
            }
            
            void backToMain(Object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                main.Visible = true;
                select.Visible = false;
                saved.Visible = false;
            }

            void savedGame(Object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                main.Visible = false;
                saved.Visible = true;
            }

            void startNewGame(Object ? sender, EventArgs e){
                select.Visible = false;
                Dungeon dungeon = new Dungeon();
                Panel game = dungeon.dungeon();
                window.Controls.Add(game);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have the second file that holds the Panel

Dungeon.cs

```
public class Dungeon{ 
    public Panel dungeon(){
        Panel gamePanel = new();
        Label test = new();
        test.Text = "Test";

        gamePanel.Width = 800;
        gamePanel.Height = 600;
        gamePanel.Controls.Add(test); 
    }
}
```

I have done this previously in Java and would be able to just import the class and access the class that holds the GUI construction in it. But in c# it does not appear to work the same.

Several issues also in the Panel1 file as it is not allowing me to use the Panel classes and other items.

Update 1/30
I have gotten the onClick to work but now issue is how to get the method to be called and created on click. As well as how do I added it to the window.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't real code - it doesn't compile. Can you provide real code? Ideally a [mcve].

Comment: As a beginner can I urge you to start off with GroupBox's instead of Panels. GroupBox do exactly what you expect, planels are for formats like flowing where its not WYSIWYG. Once you get it going then try with Panels. The second tip is in a Winform app you can use the Form Designer and drag controls from the ToolBox. If you wish to create the GUI with code (that's generated by the designer) for runtime setup then you can do it with this syntax `Panel myPanel = new Panel(); Form1.Controls.Add(myPanel);` unless making a custom control or extending a control there's no point subclassing controls.

Comment: So yes I am able to create and add the panel from within the Program.cs and do it yes at run time setup. Yes I am handwriting all code. As an example I wrote this original in Java with swing. And could use another class outside the main to hold each panel then access it. Such as window.Add(aNewClass.anewclass). The new class would be a second file with the panel fully built in it. This helps the main class from being thousands of lines

Comment: Have updated with actual code. This is a game I originally built in Java swing. But looking to change over to C#. Yes I am following some of the concepts from Java. Which I get might not work here in C#. I am using VScode because I want to get my hands into the actual code. And sorry I do not like VS.

Comment: Updated with real code and still tryng to figure out how to pull the GUI creation out of the M4Program.cs file

Comment: Just use the form designer. That’s its job. You can always look at the generated code to satisfy your curiosity – it’s doing exactly the same thing, just easier and more correct.

Comment: Its not about curiosity its about how I want to hand write this. Yes, I am sure I can do it much easier in VS but yes I know I am choosing to do it the hard way and thats ok. I enjoy the hand coding it. As stated I have this built in Java and I am sure that I do not have to create all my panels or groupbox's all in 1 file. So basically how to create multiple files with each one being able to handle a particular screen and then add them to the main form. If it can not be done so be it. but I have to assume there is a way to be able to not build everything in the main cs file.

Comment: Now contains all working code. As you see I can build it all just fine in 1 file. But really how much longer before its too long to write in.

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to solve it and have it working in a way that meets my needs at the moment.

I was able build the panel in the 2nd cs file and return the panel which was the issue I was having. As I set it to type panel but never actually returned it. Then in the main file I was able to save the return to a new Panel. Then add that to the main window

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).